# Change value of a propery before update nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, events, listener

I'm trying to change a entity property value in the PreUpdateEventListener, but the new value is not persisted, the generated sql contains the old value of the property.

The code is very simple:

```
        public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent @event)
    {
        var p = @event.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("audit_version");

        if (p != null && p.CanWrite && p.CanRead)
        {
            int val = (int)p.GetValue(@event.Entity, null);
            p.SetValue(@event.Entity, val + 1, null);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and the configuration
configuration.EventListeners.PreUpdateEventListeners = new IPreUpdateEventListener[1] { new AuditListener() };

Tks a Lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be updating @event.State, not @event.Entity. @event.State contains the data to be used in the update. You might want to update @event.Entity as well to keep everything consistent, but by the time OnPreUpdate fires, the entity's data has already been read into State. You can find the previous state as it exists in the database in @event.OldState.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found an example changing exactly the @event.State, and not the @event.Entity.

Comment: +1: You really should be updating BOTH in this case, especially if you're using second level caching, etc.

Comment: @DanP - I agree. Both should be updated in this case, but the important one is the @event.State in order to see those changes persisted.